# Numpy tutorial - Boolean indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Reading Numpy quick tutorial, I cannot understand this sentence.

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
b1 = np.array([False,True,True]) 
b2 = np.array([True,False,True,False])
>>> a[b1,b2]  
array([ 4, 10])
```

Why `a[b1,b2]` is `array([4,10])` instead of `array([[4,6],[8,10]])`?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you are performing [`integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) there.

Internally, the indices are computed from the boolean arrays -

```
In [72]: idx1 = np.flatnonzero(b1)

In [73]: idx2 = np.flatnonzero(b2)

In [75]: idx1
Out[75]: array([1, 2])

In [76]: idx2
Out[76]: array([0, 2])
```

Then, the integer array indexing is performed on each group of indices using each element from the indexing arrays -

```
In [77]: a[1,0] # 1 from idx1[0], 0 from idx2[0]
Out[77]: 4

In [78]: a[2,2] # 2 from idx1[1], 2 from idx2[1]
Out[78]: 10
```

---

To achieve that MATLAB styled block extraction, we need to use open arrays and index into each of those axes/dims. To create such open arrays in NumPy, we have [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
In [89]: np.ix_(b1,b2)
Out[89]: 
(array([[1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 2]]))

In [90]: a[np.ix_(b1,b2)]
Out[90]: 
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

Comment: @JeongYeojin If this solved your question, consider accepting it by clicking on the hollow tick next to the solution, More info here -  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work