# Access NumPy 2D array items

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

NumPy's 2D array:

```
testing = np.array([
     [   0,    0,    2,    5,    0],
     [1478, 3877, 3674, 2328, 2539],
     [1613, 4088, 3991, 6461, 2691],
     [1560, 3392, 3826, 4787, 2613],
     [1608, 4802, 3932, 4477, 2705],
     [1576, 3933, 3909, 4979, 2685],
     [  95,  229,  255,  496,  201],
     [   2,    0,    1,   27,    0],
     [1438, 3785, 3589, 4174, 2215],
     [1342, 4043, 4009, 4665, 3033]
])
```

If I do the following:

`print testing[1:3, 3:5]`

I get the following:

```
[[2328 2539] [6461 2691]]
```

And I really can't understand how did I get an output like this.

Could anyone mind explaining me how does this work? And how is the output like that?

Comment: Read up on [`integer array indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). Relevant [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44368060/3293881).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case with [1:3] you sliced the second and third row

( remember index starts at 0 and  1:3 = 1,2 ; 3 is not included )

```
    [1478, 3877, 3674, 2328, 2539],
    [1613, 4088, 3991, 6461, 2691]
```

And with  [3:5] you sliced the fourth and fifth column of even that selection. which would be by the same reasoning as above:

```
    [2328, 2539],
    [6461, 2691]
```